# NHibernate Expression.Like Criteria on Two Fields

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an Nhibernate object that has the properties Firstname and Surname, and I'd like to be able to query on both fields (Firstname + " " + Surname); e.g. If the search term is "John Doe", this will be matched when John and Doe are in seperate fields.

How can I achieve that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I ended up going with:

```
.Add(Restrictions.Like(Projections.SqlFunction("concat",
        NHibernateUtil.String,
        Projections.Property("Firstname"),
        Projections.Constant(" "),
        Projections.Property("Surname")),
    searchString, MatchMode.Anywhere))
```

Which seems to work as I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
string firstName = "John";
string lastName = "Doe";
```

for example, using LINQ:

```
Session.Query<User>()
       .Where(u => u.FirstName == firstName || u.Surname == lastName)
       .ToList();
```

you could do it with QueryOver, which looks almost the same:

```
Session.QueryOver<User>()
       .Where(u => u.FirstName == firstName || u.Surname == lastName)
       .List();
```

UPDATE:
I missed the point of the question.

what about this:

```
var name = "John Doe";
Session.Query<User>()
       .Where(u => name.Contains(u.FirstName) || name.Contains(u.Surname))
       .ToList();
```

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for, the input search string would be "John Doe" in a single term, so it needs to match against a joined field. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly be better to .split the string and search on them as parts.

Comment: Thanks, although I ended up using the Criteria API as I'm not using Linq in this project.