# (N)Hibernate : Search against 2 fields at once

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

In my project, I have a Member class with:

```
public virtual string FirstName;
public virtual string LastName;
```

I'm familiar with using Criteria and Disjunctions to search against the columns individually, but how can I set things up so that "Davie Jones" will return the people with first name Davie and last name Jones (or vice versa) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338159/nhibernate-expression-like-criteria-on-two-fields

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nHibernate 3.0, you can use `QueryOver`:

```
IEnumerable<Member> matchingMembers = iSession.QueryOver<Member>()
                                              .Where(m => m.FirstName == firstName)
                                              .And(m => m.LastName == lastName)
                                              .List<Member>();
```

Comment: This wasn't quite what I needed, as I don't have the first and last names split up.  I saw a comparable example though where you could use m => query.contains(m.FirstName).And(m => query.contains(m.LastName))